# add toggle button to the actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have `map` activity and I am trying to add `toggle button` to the actionbar next to the setting menu which contains the map type but I am facing a problem: the toggle button is being added to the setting items menu and not directly to the `actionbar`.

How can I add this toggle button to the actionbar next to the setting menu?

**map_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeNormal"
        android:title="Normal"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeSatellite"
        android:title="Satellitte"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeTerrain"
        android:title="Terrain"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeHybrid"
        android:title="Hybrid"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeNone"
        android:title="None"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_toggle"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/off"
    android:title="Share"
     />
</menu>
```

**map activity:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.map_menu, menu);
    System.out.println("ABC MAP onCreateOptionsMenu was invoked.");

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.mapTypeNone:
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
        break;

    case R.id.mapTypeNormal:
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        break;

    case R.id.mapTypeSatellite:
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        break;

    case R.id.mapTypeTerrain:
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        break;
    case R.id.mapTypeHybrid:
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_toggle:

        if (birthSort) {
            // change your view and sort it by Alphabet
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.on);
            item.setTitle("On");
            birthSort = false;
        } else {
            // change your view and sort it by Date of Birth
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.off);
            item.setTitle("Off");
            birthSort = true;
        }


    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use additional attribute *always* on menu item:

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

and it can be combined with text as well:

```
app:showAsAction="withText|always"
```

Adjust your namespace accordingly. Here is a complete sample:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item
      android:id="@+id/action_sync"
      android:title="@string/action_sync"
      app:showAsAction="withText|always"/>
</menu>
```

Pay attention to the *app:* prefix for showAsAction and the corresponding namespace declaration.

Comment: I have added it to all items of the menu except `<item android:id="@+id/menu_toggle" `but nothing changed. It is always being displayed in the setting menu also with the map type items.